# Why are we still in beta?

Tags: discussion, site-activity

Im just wondering.

Why is  Econ SE still in beta in-spite of having a strong committed community?

What is stopping us from progressing to the next stage of site development?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read about the Stack Exchange graduation policy here: [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)

Here's the key part:

> The TL;DR:
>
> 1. When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation.
> 2. If a public beta site does not produce consistently helpful content, and lacks the caretakers needed for flags and spam to get handled and our Be Nice policy to be upheld, it will be closed.
>
> Is your site in between these two categories? You don’t have anything to worry about. Regardless of how small the site might be, you have a home here in the SE network.

But we should not try to game this system because the decision is taken by human community moderators who will look at what is goin on on the site (and because the long term interest of the site are best served by genuine organic growth).

Comment: I would note that 10 questions per day is not a firm guideline. Many sites have been graduated ([Workplace SE is a notable example](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace)) with 6-7 questions per day.

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be is that we are too small. We are currently failing the "questions per day", "answered" and "answer ratio" indicators of Area 51:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics

Comment: Is this an automatic decision of the area51 algorithms, or is there also a human decision related to this? 
I guess we could start an "answer week rush" or something to try to get to the 90% answer ration, but several questions are very hard to answer, or need moderation for the homework policy...

Comment: @JoaoBotelho it is, and always has been, a human decision, by StackExchange employees. The area51 criteria have been superceded, and are now obsolete. See the answer by Ubiquitous for the current situation.

Answer (score 2):

As Ubiquitous answer clarified, SE sites graduate with criteria **akin to a sustainable business:**

1) Is there enough and sustained *demand* for our services? ("10 questions per day consistently")

2) Can the business be depended upon to deliver the services it promises at adequate quality ("consistently helpful content", i.e. answers voted up by the community and/or accepted by the OP)?

3) Is the business adequately organized so that it doesn't fall apart for internal reasons ("flags, caretakers", etc)?